# Number and date format : altering NLS_SESSION_PARAMETER does not work?

Tags: session, oracle-apex, number-formatting, date-formatting, nls

Oracle 11.2.0.3.0, APEX 4.1.1.00.23.

We need to display **numbers** in our application with the format `FM999999999990.000` and **dates** with the English format `DD-MON-YYYY`.

Even if the application language is going to change (french, spain, etc.), we always need this format for numbers (no space or comma for group separator, and a point for decimal separator, *ie. -1254.010*) and date (3 first letters from the English month name *ie. 12-FEB-2012*).

Here are **globalization attributes** we are using (*Application Builder -> Application -> Edit Globalization Attributes*) :

- Application Primary Language: *French (France) (fr)*
- Application Language Derived From: *Session*
- Application Date Format: *DD-MON-YYYY*

I cannot manage to make it work as expected...
I still get numbers like `-1254,01` and dates like `12-FÉVR.-2012` instead of `-1254.010` and `12-FEB-2012`.
It seems APEX ignore any call to alter session...

I have tried to enter the following code in the "**Initialization PL/SQL Code**" attribute (*Application Builder -> Application -> Edit Security Attributes*) but without any success :

```
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= ''.,'' ';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ''AMERICAN'' ';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_LANGUAGE = ''AMERICAN'' ';
END;
```

I have a report with the following query to see if parameters are changing :

```
SELECT
  a1.parameter as "Parameter",
  a1.value as "Database value",
  a2.value as "Instance value",
  a3.value as "Session value"
FROM
  nls_database_parameters a1
  LEFT JOIN nls_instance_parameters a2 ON a1.parameter = a2.parameter
  LEFT JOIN nls_session_parameters a3 ON a1.parameter = a3.parameter
ORDER BY
  a1.parameter asc;
```

Result:

[image: report NLS parameters no changes]

As you see `ALTER SESSION` calls don't change anything...

When I try `ALTER SESSION` calls in a "**Before Header**" application process, session seems to be altered (report show modified values), but I still get wrong date and number format in my reports and items...
I have tried the "**Format Mask**" attribute of the "**Number Field**" items but it seems it does not change anything too...

The only way I can get it to work is to call `ALTER SESSION` in each PL/SQL function I call from APEX. And for reports I can use the "Number / Date Format" column attribute.

**QUESTION:** Is there any way I can alter number and date parameters for the session for the whole application ?

---

### EDIT :

When I run the following **Before Header process** on each page :

```
BEGIN
   APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_LANG('fr');
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS= ''.,'' ';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE = ''AMERICAN'' ';
END;
```

the report shows that the session has been altered :

[image: report NLS parameters]

Then I have created a new test page with :

1. The above Before Header process.
2. A report to show NLS parameters values.
3. A report that show date and numbers from one of my tables.
4. A textfield items with a Source Type as "SQL Query" to get a date.
5. A Number field item with a Source Type as "SQL Query" to get a number.
6. A button bound with JQuery that calls an application process that calls a PL/SQL procedure that `htp.prn()` a date from a table, then fill my textfield item.
7. A button bound with JQuery that do an insert (using application process, etc.) of the two fields in a table.

Once the page is loaded, report shows that the session has been altered coorectly, and I got right number and date formats, in the items and in the report. The "insert" button do the insertion without any problem.

When I click the "getDate" button to get a date from the database using an ajax call, I get the date in the French format! And then the "insert" button fails (`invalid date`).

**Do you have any idea on why getting values from JavaScript** (making an ajax call to an On Demand Application Process that calls a PL/SQL function in a package) **causes the problem ?**

And it is still strange as in my other existing pages, I get wrong format in the report even if I use the same Before Header process. We have to look more into this with my collegue, maybe we have a "hidden" piece of code somewhere which breaks all.

I have looked at the debug message data for the page but nothing strange for me.

Comment: Could you per chance try this out on apex.oracle.com and see how it reacts there? I'll try and give this a whirl in my environment too.

Comment: I will not have time today, but I can give a try early next week. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to you: i tried this with just nls_numeric_characters and i don't seem to get any problems with this. Does your database user for the schema have rights to alter? If you run the alter sessions from, say, sql developer, does it work then?

Comment: Yes database user has required privileges for altering the session. And I see that the session is altered correctly so it should not be the problem.
I have edited my post to add some information.
Thank you for trying to help, I will implement an example on apex.oracle.com if the problem persists.

Comment: It's a good post with lots of information, i wish i could help more. Maybe try bumping your post on OTN again? I do suppose that the ajax retrieval is because it is another session that gets used for it. I wouldn't actually have expected your before-headers process with alter session to carry through to your page processing too, but i'd need to read into apex + db sessions management to really know how that works.  It's also weird that your application properties>security settings won't take effect for you, it did fine for me.

Comment: As fac586 tells me on OTN, in fact security settings are applied but immediately superseded by the SESSION Language setting, and this is the main problem I think.
A solution is to derive application language from application item FSP_LANGUAGE_PREFERENCE instead of Session. I have tested and all is working fine.
However I'm sure there is a solution while keeping the application language derived from the session. I will continue investigating :)

Comment: I hope some expert hops on the thread - it's interesting. Good thing you're one step further!

Answer (score 1):

Are you working with this in an Apex application?  If so, then part of the application creation process is specifying NLS related values.  Apex will always override your settings with the application settings.

[image]

I always create applications with fixed NLS values so I am sure that dates and numbers will be shown correctly.

You can have Apex switch NLS settings  (application preference, item preference).  Those work just fine.

But you need to do it on the application level and not database level.

Answer (score 1):

Each call from apex-client to server is the separate oracle session.
It answers why you are getting wrong format by js callback.

Have you tried this?

The Application Express session language can be set via either the **APEX_UTIL.SET_SESSION_LANG** procedure or via the **P_LANG** parameter of the F procedure in the URL.

Also you can try put initialization code here:  Security Attributes -> Database Session -> Initialization PL/SQL Code. But I'm not sure about callbacks.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry I can't tell you just why the Globalization Attributes aren't "sticking" across languages, as I'm lucky enough to not have to worry about it.  Have you tried using a substitution variable here rather than putting the literal in?  It *shouldn't* fix this, but it's worth a shot, eh?  I tried playing with this a bit, setting the value for an application item := SYSDATE.  When I changed the Application->Global Settings->Application Date Format, it would apply the specified format each time I redisplayed the page the page item was on.

Separately, it's hard for me to imagine that your user has the privileges to alter the session for the APEX_PUBLIC_USER schema, which is where your application is run from.  That is, I have a hard time imagining that a DBA would grant that permission, as it seems pretty dangerous for that account.

Also, remember that the Apex sessions (as indicated by the session ID in the URL) are different than Oracle sessions.  So your anonymous block above may actually be able to alter the session within the Oracle session it's running in for the test page you mentioned above, but you AJAX call conversation with the database will be run in a different Oracle session.  So the 'ALTER SESSION' would have no effect on it.

I hope this discussion helps you find your answer.  If so, please give me props!  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it answers your question but this link has just saved my day :

- [Setting the NLS_LANG Environment Variable for Oracle Databases](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12102_01/books/AnyInstAdm784/AnyInstAdmPreInstall18.html)

In my case , I have a French environment and I need an "American Oracle database" (localization). Each time I was creating a session for `sqlldr` I had a French NLS (although I needed an American one).

Here is a copy of this page in case it disappears :

---

---

### Follow this procedure to set the `NLS_LANG` environment variable for Oracle databases.

To set the `NLS_LANG` environment variable for Oracle databases, we have to determine the `NLS_LANG` value.

Run the command :

```
SELECT * FROM V$NLS_PARAMETERS
```

Make a note of the NLS_LANG value, which is in the format `[NLS_LANGUAGE]_[NLS_TERRITORY].[NLS_CHARACTERSET]`.

For example: **American_America.UTF8**

### For Windows:

- Navigate to `Control Panel > System` and click the `Advanced tab`. Click `Environment Variables`.
- In `System variables` section, click `New`.
- In the Variable Name field, enter `NLS_LANG`.
- In the Variable Value field, enter the NLS_LANG value that was returned in Step 1 (for example : `American_America.UTF8`).

### For UNIX, set the variable as shown below:

```
setenv NLS_LANG <NLS_LANG>
```

For example:

```
setenv NLS_LANG American_America.UTF8.
```

If your data is 7-bit or 8-bit ASCII and the Informatica Server is running on UNIX, then set

```
NLS_LANG <NLS_LANGUAGE>_<NLS_TERRITORY>.WE8ISO8859P1
```

**CAUTION**:  Make sure you set the NLS_LANG variable correctly, as stated in this procedure, or your data will not display correctly.

**Reboot the machine after creating the variable.**